# My Minesweeper program written in Python is revealing the whole board - Recursion issues

Tags: python, recursion, python-3.x, minesweeper

I'm trying to write a Minesweeper program using Python. Everything is working fine except for my cascading reveal. Here is what I have:

```
def rippleEffect(self, r, c):
     if self.ActualBoard[r][c] == 0:
      self.GameBoard[r][c] = self.ActualBoard[r][c]
      rcchar = str(sum(1
                      for rr in (r-1, r, r+1)
                      for cc in (c-1, c, c+1)))
      for rr in (r-1, r, r+1):
        for cc in (c-1, c, c+1):
          if self.ActualBoard[rr][cc] != 'M' and self.ActualBoard[rr][cc] > 0:
            self.GameBoard[rr][cc] = self.ActualBoard[rr][cc]
          else:
            try:
              if (rr,cc) != (r,c) and self.GameBoard[rr][cc] == 'H':
                self.rippleEffect(rr, cc)
            except IndexError: 
              pass
```

ActualBoard consists of list of lists with everything revealed, ie:

```
[[0, 1, 1, 1], [0, 1, M, 1], [0, 1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

for a 4x4 board with one mine.

GameBoard consists of a list of lists as well but when the game starts it would look like so:

```
[['H','H', 'H', 'H'], ['H','H', 'H', 'H'], ['H','H', 'H', 'H'], ['H','H', 'H', 'H']]
```

Comment: Think about your logic some more.  The problem has nothing to do with Python, it is that you are  not doing what you intend to do.

Comment: I figured out what was wrong. for var in (var - 1, var, and var +1) was giving me negative numbers at some point cause it to index backwards. I just had to check that it wasn't a negative number.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Think about this: if `r == 0` and `c == 0`, what will `self.GameBoard[r-1][c-1]` be? More specifically, would it raise an IndexError?

Comment: It wouldn't raise and IndexError it would just go to the last instance of the board. I see what you're saying

    'if (rr,cc) != (r,c) and self.GameBoard[rr][cc] == 'H':'
 
should be

    'if (rr,cc) != (r,c) and self.GameBoard[rr][cc] == 'H' and rr >=0 '

and cc >= 0:
correct?

Comment: Yes, that should stop it cascading all the way around

Comment: I appreciate you not giving me the direct answer but getting the thought process going.